# How to check The number of monitor in javascript ? possible？

Tags: javascript, reactjs, monitor

I need to know the number of monitors and then display the corresponding amount of workspace。

I do not know whether there is a way to achieve with javascript。

i use [react-popout](https://github.com/JakeGinnivan/react-popout) to open new webpage.

Comment: But...isn't your page running in a browser window with a size that the *user* sets independent of how many monitors their computer has?

Comment: compatible all of the browers

Comment: @nnnnnn 
Simply put that is necessary to access the computer hardware information through javascript

Comment: The only way I can think of would be to first check `window.screen` which will output some info on the monitor where your page is running, then try to open popups in 4 directions, according to the main Screen's .width and .height and check their own `screen`  property. Hacky, easily blockable by users, and not recommended thus only in a comment.  (chrome scripts (aka extensions) will have access to more info, if it's an option to you)